# dependency issues with react & digitalocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am experiencing an annoying conflict with node & npm when I am installing dependencies and peerdependencies within react. I have tried everything in my powers.

Basically, I can install the package.json modules using npm i -legacy-peer-deps.
However, when I try to deploy and build within digitalocean I can't seem to get it to run any legacy options to install the dependencies forcefully.

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "job-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "8.12.1",
    "node": "16.15.1",
    "react": "17.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "2.11.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@pathofdev/react-tag-input": "1.0.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.6.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars": "19.3.53",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "7.1.2",
    "@typeform/embed-react": "1.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.8",
    "@types/node": "12.20.37",
    "@types/react": "16.14.21",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "0.31.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.14",
    "@types/react-modal": "3.13.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.20",
    "@types/react-router": "5.1.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.2",
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "canvg": "3.0.9",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "csv": "5.5.3",
    "date-fns": "2.26.0",
    "daterangepicker": "3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "16.0.1",
    "draft-js": "0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "0.9.1",
    "export-to-csv": "0.2.1",
    "faster-react-tabs": "1.0.4",
    "i18next": "20.6.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "6.1.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "1.3.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "3.2.2",
    "interactjs": "1.10.11",
    "jspdf": "2.4.0",
    "jspdf-autotable": "3.5.23",
    "lodash.debounce": "4.0.8",
    "match-sorter": "6.3.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.34",
    "react-big-calendar": "0.33.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.6.4",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-collapsible": "2.8.4",
    "react-confirm-alert": "2.7.0",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "1.7.0",
    "react-csv": "2.0.3",
    "react-data-export": "^0.4.2",
    "react-datepicker": "3.8.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "1.14.7",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "0.11.5",
    "react-export-excel": "0.5.3",
    "react-fa-icon-picker": "1.0.3",
    "react-facebook-login": "4.1.1",
    "react-facebook-login-typed": "5.0.3",
    "react-google-login": "5.2.2",
    "react-hooks-multi-step-wizard": "0.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "11.14.2",
    "react-icons": "4.3.1",
    "react-linechart": "^1.1.9",
    "react-modal": "3.14.4",
    "react-moment": "1.1.1",
    "react-multi-select-component": "4.1.14",
    "react-notification-bar": "1.0.8",
    "react-qr-code": "2.0.3",
    "react-recaptcha": "2.3.10",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "3.2.22",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "3.2.0",
    "react-step-wizard": "5.3.9",
    "react-table": "7.7.0",
    "react-timeago": "6.2.1",
    "react-tiny-tabs": "0.1.2",
    "react-toastify": "8.1.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@interactjs/types": "1.10.11",
    "@types/jspdf": "2.0.0",
    "@types/match-sorter": "6.0.0",
    "@types/react-alert": "5.2.1",
    "@types/react-calendar-timeline": "0.26.5",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "3.1.8",
    "@types/react-facebook-login": "4.1.4",
    "@types/react-helmet": "6.1.4",
    "@types/react-select": "3.1.2",
    "@types/react-table": "7.7.8",
    "@types/react-timeago": "4.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.33.0",
    "css-loader": "5.2.7",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.27.1",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "7.3.0",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.9.10",
    "@sweetalert/with-react": "0.1.1",
    "sweetalert": "2.1.2"
  }
}
```

```
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.12.1` to update!
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm notice 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! While resolving: @sweetalert/with-react@0.1.1
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! Found: react-dom@17.0.2
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   react-dom@"^17.0.2" from the root project
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.3" from the root project
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.1" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.61
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/lab
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!       @material-ui/lab@"^4.0.0-alpha.60" from the root project
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     1 more (@material-ui/pickers)
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   25 more (@material-ui/lab, @material-ui/pickers, ...)
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! peer react-dom@"^16.x.x" from @sweetalert/with-react@0.1.1
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! node_modules/@sweetalert/with-react
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   @sweetalert/with-react@"^0.1.1" from the root project
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^16.x.x" from @sweetalert/with-react@0.1.1
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!   node_modules/@sweetalert/with-react
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     @sweetalert/with-react@"^0.1.1" from the root project
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! See /home/apps/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] npm ERR!     /home/apps/.npm/_logs/2022-06-13T18_57_40_915Z-debug-0.log
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] unable to invoke layer creator
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] installing node_modules: exit status 1
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:43] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:45] 
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:45] For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
[move-butler-ui] [2022-06-13 18:57:45]    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed the issue by downgrading to
"npm": "6.14.15",
"node": "14.18.2",

Comment: I also updated to react v18 and ended up using 8.14.0 and node v16. This fixed my app

Answer (score 0):

Convert the whole react project  to yarn by deleting the node_module and package.lock.json and run yarn install